# Mirror Local Data Store - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, local, mirror

So this might not be the best code specific question but I am just looking for some advice to achieve my desired set-up.

Im building a POS system for a local restaurant that has a requirement of being fully operational offline. We will be setting up 3 iPads that all need to be in sync with each other and store all the data locally to later be pushed to the remote server. All iPads will be hardwired with ethernet cables to the LAN.

GOAL: I would like to share a local database (Something like Parse Local Datastore or Core Data) on 3 iPads (all hardwired to the same network) - and all iPads can read and update the data simultaneously - last save will be the most recent object for all devices

What I've been doing:

1. Parse + Parse Local Database: It seems like a pretty good option and works perfect with one iPad, however now I basically need to find a way to mirror the local database on the three ipads
2. Multi-peer connectivity: used to pass new or updated data to nearby iPads - I have successfully implemented this breaking down PFObject's to custom objects to be passed to other ipads. Is passing the data separately to each iPad then rebuilding PFObjects to store locally going to be my best option?

Other options I just came across:

1. NSPersistentContainer - Core data mirroring with CloudKit
2. Realm, SQLite, Firebase - I'm open to any solution but something like Firebase would probably require me to migrate the customer app from parse to firebase

Basically I need a remote-like database but only on a local network (no internet connection) that can only be accessed by devices on that network. Is this possible?

Or I have to break down objects, pass them to nearby iPads then reconstruct and store locally, but I feel like this leaves a lot of room for the local databases to not match each other.

Has anybody faced a problem like this and can outline a solution? I don't need the code just an understanding of how you would recommend handling this situation. Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/719/